# Error creating an ERC20 TOKEN - GAS LIMIT EXCEEDED

Tags: erc-20, error

I've been trying to create an erc20 token experimentally, I've been trying to follow [this](https://hashnode.com/post/how-to-build-your-own-ethereum-based-erc20-token-and-launch-an-ico-in-next-20-minutes-cjbcpwzec01c93awtbij90uzn) tutorial .

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Token {

/// @return total amount of tokens
function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply) {}

/// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
/// @return The balance
function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {}

/// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
/// @param _to The address of the recipient
/// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
/// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

/// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
/// @param _from The address of the sender
/// @param _to The address of the recipient
/// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
/// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

/// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_addr` to spend `_value` tokens
/// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
/// @param _value The amount of wei to be approved for transfer
/// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

/// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
/// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
/// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {}

event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}

contract StandardToken is Token {

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    //Default assumes totalSupply can't be over max (2^256 - 1).
    //If your token leaves out totalSupply and can issue more tokens as time goes on, you need to check if it doesn't wrap.
    //Replace the if with this one instead.
    //if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    //same as above. Replace this line with the following if you want to protect against wrapping uints.
    //if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
    if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
  return allowed[_owner][_spender];
}

mapping (address => uint256) balances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
uint256 public totalSupply;
}

contract HashnodeTestCoin is StandardToken { // CHANGE THIS. Update the contract name.

/* Public variables of the token */

/*
NOTE:
The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
*/
string public name;                   // Token Name
uint8 public decimals;                // How many decimals to show. To be standard complicant keep it 18
string public symbol;                 // An identifier: eg SBX, XPR etc..
string public version = 'H1.0'; 
uint256 public unitsOneEthCanBuy;     // How many units of your coin can be bought by 1 ETH?
uint256 public totalEthInWei;         // WEI is the smallest unit of ETH (the equivalent of cent in USD or satoshi in BTC). We'll store the total ETH raised via our ICO here.  
address public fundsWallet;           // Where should the raised ETH go?

// This is a constructor function 
// which means the following function name has to match the contract name declared above
function HashnodeTestCoin() {
    balances[msg.sender] = 10000;               // Give the creator all initial tokens. This is set to 1000 for example. If you want your initial tokens to be X and your decimal is 5, set this value to X * 100000. (CHANGE THIS)
    totalSupply = 10000;                        // Update total supply (1000 for example) (CHANGE THIS)
    name = "Paws";                                   // Set the name for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
    decimals = 0;                                               // Amount of decimals for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
    symbol = "PAW";                                             // Set the symbol for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
    unitsOneEthCanBuy = 0;                                      // Set the price of your token for the ICO (CHANGE THIS)
    fundsWallet = msg.sender;                                    // The owner of the contract gets ETH
}

function() payable{
    totalEthInWei = totalEthInWei + msg.value;
    uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy;
    if (balances[fundsWallet] < amount) {
        return;
    }

    balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet] - amount;
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + amount;

    Transfer(fundsWallet, msg.sender, amount); // Broadcast a message to the blockchain

    //Transfer ether to fundsWallet
    fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);                               
}

/* Approves and then calls the receiving contract */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

    //call the receiveApproval function on the contract you want to be notified. This crafts the function signature manually so one doesn't have to include a contract in here just for this.
    //receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _tokenContract, bytes _extraData)
    //it is assumed that when does this that the call *should* succeed, otherwise one would use vanilla approve instead.
    if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { throw; }
    return true;
}
}
```

After which i get the following error ,

```
creation of HashnodeTestCoin errored: Gas required exceeds limit: 0. An                 
important gas estimation might also be the sign of a problem in the contract   
code. Please check loops and be sure you did not sent value to a non payable  
function (that's also the reason of strong gas estimation).
```

I have the ropsten network working on my metamask. It's my first time working with solidity so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the gas limit in the Remix browser IDE set to zero, try increasing this to the default figure of 3000000 and create the contract again.